# Negative mutual information example. What's wrong about it?

Tags: information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

I'm aware that *by definition* the Mutual Information (MI) should be non-negative, and there are two related questions here: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868285/confusion-about-non-negative-mutual-information) and [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3238521/meaning-of-negative-mutual-information).

However, I can think of an example in Physics where it is (or at least it seems to be) negative. So, please, point to where my reasoning is wrong.

First, write the $MI$ as
$$
    MI(Y;X) = H(Y) - H(Y|X)\ ,
$$
where $X\to$ input signal; $Y\to$ output signal. The discrete stochastic variables $X$ and $Y$ keep jumping between each of its $k$-th state over time (different states for either $X$ or $Y$).

Say I simulated the stochastic process $Y$ with and without the input $X$. For the sake of the example, consider that $Y$ has 10 states. Say without input, the distribution $\mathcal{P}_0(Y_k)$ that I observed in the simulations is a power law
$$
\mathcal{P}_0(Y_k)=\frac{k^{-1}}{\sum_{k=1}^{10}k^{-1}}\ ;
$$
whereas with input, I observed a uniform distribution $\mathcal{P}_X(Y_k)$
$$
\mathcal{P}_X(Y_k)=1/10\ .
$$

Now, the first term in the $MI$ formula is simply
$$
H(Y)=-\sum_{k=1}^{10} \mathcal{P}_0(Y_k) \log_2 \mathcal{P}_0(Y_k)\approx 1.9938~{\rm bits}\ ,
$$
and the entropy given input is (at least I'm assuming it is empirically given by)
$$
H(Y|X)=-\sum_{k=1}^{10} \mathcal{P}_X(Y_k) \log_2 \mathcal{P}_X(Y_k)\approx 2.3026~{\rm bits}\ ,
$$
which yields $MI(Y;X)\approx-0.3088~{\rm bits}<0$.

I suspect the problem is in this last step. In other words, can I really apply this entropy formula to $\mathcal{P}_X(Y_k)$?

I assume I can, since I measured $Y$ for a *long time* while the input $X$ was being delivered to $Y$. Or can't I? And if I can't, then why is it and how should I go about it?

Consider I have access only to the distribution of the output states $\mathcal{P}_X(Y_k)$, and the input $X$ is a Poisson process. How should $H(Y|X)$ be written?

*PS:* this example is illustrative, but this is basically what happens in the mean-field simulations of systems in the directed percolation universality class (such as the mean-field contact process, or any mean-field branching process): the distribution of states when input tends to zero is power law (at the critical point for the branching ratio parameter), and the distribution of states turns into uniform as Poisson input rate increases.

Answer (score 2):

You're not computing the right thing at all.

The conditional entropy of $Y$ given $X$ is *defined* as $$ - \sum_x P_X(x) \sum_y P_{Y|X}(y|x)\log P_{Y|X}(y|x). $$ This is necessarily smaller than $H(P_Y) = - \sum P_Y(y) \log P_Y(y)$, where note that we must compare the marginal over $Y$ of the *joint law* of $(X,Y)$, i.e., that $P_Y$ must satisfy that for each $y, P_Y(y) = \sum_x P_X(x) P_{Y|X}(y|x)$. Note that $H(Y) \ge H(Y|X)$ is a mathematical certainty, and is just a consequence of convexity.

In the question, compare your computation of $H(Y|X)$ with the formula above, and I guess you'll see the gap. Effectively, you have just described two laws on a random variable $Y$, $P^1,P^2,$ and say that the entropy under one law is larger than the entropy under the second law. This is not surprising at all, I hope :).

Comment: I can understand the "mathematics" of your statement, but it is really hard for me to translate this conditional entropy formula to a practical example. Since I measured $\mathcal{P}_X(Y_k)$ [in my example] from the process under influence of the input, wouldn't the actual information of the input be recorded into this observed distribution?

Comment: And if the input information isn't really in the observed $\mathcal{P}_X(Y_k)$, then how should I approach measuring the $H(Y|X)$ in practice? From the wikipedia page, I'm guessing I have to simulate the process $Y$ for many different realizations of the input $X$, and then average the observed entropy over the realizations of $X$. Basically, I think I can simulate $Y$ for a long time and bootstrap its sampling to get different $H(Y)$ over which I can average. But this also yields negative $MI$.

Comment: The error might be in your computation of $H(Y)$, then. It seems like the following is true (but correct me): for (all?, various?, randomly drawn?) values of $x$, you understand $P_{Y|X}(\cdot|x)$ well (via, say, sampling and simulation). Let's say that $H(Y|X = x) := -\sum_y P_{Y|X}(y|x) \log P_{Y|X}(y|x)$. Then you can compute $H(Y|X) = \sum P_X(x) H(Y|X = x),$ which is indeed can be estimated by an average over the $X$s you have sampled. But $H(Y)$, then, needs to work with the marginal over $Y$, i.e., what should go into computing $H(Y)$ is $P_{Y}(y) = \sum_x P_{Y|X}(y|x) P_X(x)$.

Comment: (contd.) This is also an average, so you can estimate this law at the end of your sampling, and then plug this into the entropy formula (this is not always a good idea, but it's not unreasonable if you have enough samples).  From reading the question more closely, it seems that you have computed $H(Y|X = 0)$ and $H(Y|X = x)$ for some value of $x$, and then taken their difference. This doesn't as such capture things, I'd say.

Comment: I'd suppose there's also the broader question of _why_ you want to compute mutual information, which might help in understanding your question better. Also if there's correlation between $X$s and $Y$s in various time steps, then this could induce significant biases in your estimates, and thus if so you probably need to be aware and take the numbers you get with a grain of salt. Nevertheless, if the $P_Y$ you plug in is indeed the average as above, at least nonnegativity should not be a problem (up to potentially small errors due to biases in plug-in estimation of $H(Y)$)

Comment: I'm digesting your comments and the subject slowly. Now I think that what I called $P_X$ in my example is in fact either $P(Y|X)$ or $P(x,y)$. $Y$ is the output firing rate of a neural network, and $X$ is the input Poisson process (with rate r) independently delivered to every neuron in the network. Every neuron is a 0 or 1 unit, so the output $Y=S/N$ where $S$ is the sum of all (output) 1's at each time step, and the average input is $X=P(r)=1-e^{-r}$ at each time step (the probability of a "1" input from the Poisson process averaged over the N neurons it is delivered to).

Comment: (contd.) I measured the output rate $Y$ as a response to the input $X$ already, yielding the $P_X$ distribution. Thus, I believe that this is $P(Y|X)$ (even intuitively speaking). So in order to get the entropy, I need to average the sum I have over the inputs... And since the input is a Poisson process, I'm guessing the the P of inputs is probably a binomial distribution